# Mvc Facebook Application Debugging at localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have a mvc proj which is page of facebook application. I want to debug it in my localhost when ı call it from facebook. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, provide the `Site_url/Cavas_url` to `http://localhost/yourapp/` and `enable` the `sandbox mode`

Comment: İts working, Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

There are options for testing/debugging the application from localhost, specifically: site url and sandbox (yes/no). But changing these settings of an application that already is used in production will break the application in for your visitors.

A common method is to create multiple applications, where the amount depends on your development method. For example: one for development, one for testing and one for production. The development app will point to something like: localhost:8000, the test app will point to something like test.yourapplication.com and the development app will point to www.yourapplication.com.